# PHP/PDO function return value from database variable parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to write this basic function to get a value from a table.

```
<?php 
    function getvalue($value, $from, $id){
        //Returns the value of a table

        require('includes/connect.php');
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password); 
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        $sql = "SELECT :value AS value
            FROM :from
            WHERE id = :id
            LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':from', $from, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $data = $stmt->fetch();
        $return = $data['value'];

        return $return;
    }//function
?>
```

It gives this Fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''project' WHERE id = '1'' at line 2' in /functions/getvalue.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /functions/getvalue.php(26): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /
>   test.php(24): getvalue('tarief', 'project', '1') #2 {main} thrown in /functions/getvalue.php on line 26

Comment: You can't have a table name or column names as bound parameters.

Comment: Is there an other way how to write this function, or is it no possible at all?

Comment: The only way you can do it is by including the variable directly in the string, which opens the door to SQL injections. However - what you can do is generate a whitelist of tables and their columns from the database, and validate the values you're looking for against that list.

Answer (score 2):

Although your idea of having such a function is excellent, the implementation is just terrible. Some essential drawbacks are:

- you are connecting to database every time this function is called
- this code is prone to SQL injection
- yet it is awfully inflexible, letting you to run no query different from silly `SELECT ... WHERE id`. Eventually you will learn other queries and find this function unusable.

It should be a function that accepts an SQL query and array with parameters to bind:

```
<?php 
//Returns the value of a query
function getvalue($sql, $params = array())
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute($params); 
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

require('includes/connect.php');
$name = getValue("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id =?",array($_GET['id']))
```

simple, robust and usable.

While connection string better to be moved into includes/connect.php

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
```

Comment: why global $pdo? why not just send it as function parameter?

Comment: although I agree that it's a bit inflexible as it is, isn't the point of a `getValue()` function to select a single field?

Comment: at first, I was wondering why I would need to have more flexibility in a task which is not very flexible at all, but then couldn't find any downside of writing the query each time you use the function over sending four or five parameters to it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this (be sure $value and $from variables values are escaped):

```
<?php 
    function getvalue($value, $from, $id){
        //Returns the value of a table

        require('includes/connect.php');
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password); 
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        $sql = "SELECT " . $value . " AS value
            FROM " . $from . "
            WHERE id = :id
            LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $data = $stmt->fetch();
        $return = $data['value'];

        return $return;
    }//function
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong with an answer that I got minus?? He/She wanted to fix the problem, it does fix it. There was no thinking on "better" way of doing it.

Comment: I think some people have objected to you going back a decade by inserting the arbitrary strings into your $sql. In principle if you don't pass any user input into those parameters, you are safe, but if a function like this lays around the code base for a while, somebody may feed it $_POST['from'] or something, and you can be in a load of trouble.